# Store class objects in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, kotlin

I am working on a simple app (To-Do List app). I created a class called `tasks`:

```
class tasks(var title:String, var time:String)
```

and stored some `tasks` in an `ArrayList`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    var tasks_list = ArrayList<tasks>(tasks("hello","3am"),tasks("meet amy","5pm"))
}
```

But still it gives me an error:
[image: the error]

Can you please explain why it doesn't work? And how to print out a `task`. Thanks.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf6bG.png

Comment: that is no error, that is a red squiggly line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not initializing the `ArrayList` correctly.

You might do something like:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var tasks_list = arrayListOf<tasks>(tasks("hello","3am"), tasks("meet amy","5pm"))
    println(tasks_list)
}
```

Instead. Alternatively, this would also work:

```
var tasks_list = arrayListOf<tasks>()
tasks_list.add(tasks("hello","3am"))
tasks_list.add(tasks("meet amy","5pm"))
println("Tasks list:")
println(tasks_list)
```

However, without overriding `toString()` this would only print some kind of object reference that looks like the following:

```
Tasks list:
[tasks@28a418fc, tasks@5305068a]
```

In your `tasks` class, you should override `toString()` so that it prints something useful, like follows:

```
class tasks(var title:String, var time:String) {

    override fun toString() : String = "{Title: $title. Time: $time}"

}
```

Now your output will look as follows:

```
Tasks list:
[{Title: hello. Time: 3am}, {Title: meet amy. Time: 5pm}]
```

EDIT:

Regarding your comment, if you wish to print properties of the class individually, you can simply use the getters of this class. These are autogenerated and in this case have `public` access.

So you could iterate over all `tasks` in the list as follows:

```
    for(task in tasks_list) {
        println(task.title)
        println(task.time)
    }
```

Which would print out:

```
hello
3am
meet amy
5pm
```

Or:

```
    for(i in 0..tasks_list.size-1) {
        println("Task #: $i")
        println(tasks_list.get(i).title)
        println(tasks_list.get(i).time)
    }
```

(Note the `-1`, since the range operator is *inclusive*) Which would print out:

```
Task #: 0
hello
3am
Task #: 1
meet amy
5pm
```

I highly recommend reading some basic documentation (like [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html)) before continuing, as these are very basic things that you would do well to learn before trying to do anything else.

Comment: Thank you so much, It solved my problem. But can I print out the title and the time separated?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please also consult the official Kotlin [reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/) as well as some of the [tutorials](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/) on the official language page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the resources and for this problem solving! Just thanks!